# Enabling SSO to Office 365 and Get Client Context to Other .Net Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, adfs, office-365-developer, sso

We have requirement to enable SSO in office 365 and get client context to other web page? Is it possible? How I can achieve?

Comment: do you have azure AD ?